# Javascript - SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var UserCharacter = {
  UserID: util.getCookie('u_u');
  userUsingThisCharacter: function() {
    var data = {};
    data.UserID = UserCharacter.UserID;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: util.API_URL + "character",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        var user = JSON.parse(result);
        //PlayerUserCharactertoMainScreenInitialize = user;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, text) {
        Alerts.Error("Algo de errado aconteceu, entre em contacto com o dono do sistema!");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is in Portuguese, and that "Alerts.(something)" are another function I made to appear a custom alert. The problem is up there in line 1. I tried to run that code and the following error appears:

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list Player.js:2:31 note: { opened at line 1, column 20

I have ran through the code over and over and over and I can't find anything. I hope you can help me.
If I'm missing any information, please be considerate and just tell me, I'm not really feeling well and this is draining me.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: `{
  UserID: util.getCookie('u_u');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the very first semicolon:

```
var UserCharacter = {
  UserID: util.getCookie('u_u'); // <-- this should be a comma.

  userUsingThisCharacter: function() {
    var data = {};

    data.UserID = UserCharacter.UserID;

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: util.API_URL + "character",
      data: data,

      cache: false,


      success: function(result) {
        var user = JSON.parse(result);
        //PlayerUserCharactertoMainScreenInitialize = user;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, text) {
        Alerts.Error("Algo de errado aconteceu, entre em contacto com o dono do sistema!");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Goodness, that's right. I always fail to notice that. Thank you so much and thanks to every other answer.

Answer (score 0):

`UserCharacter` is an `Object`, its properties must be separated by commas. Here you have `UserID: util.getCookie('u_u');` ending with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

`UserCharacter` is actually a JavaScript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), so you need to put a comma to separate the object keys like:

```
var UserCharacter = {
   UserID: util.getCookie('u_u'),
   userUsingThisCharacter: function() {
      // your code here
   },

   // you can add more key values here separated by comma like
   active: false,
   oneMoreFunction: function() {},
   oneMoreObjectKey: { foo: 1, bar: true }
}
```

Demo:

```js
var UserCharacter = {
  UserID: 23,
  userUsingThisCharacter: function() {
    return this.UserID; // You can access UserID using this
  }
}

console.log(UserCharacter.userUsingThisCharacter());
```